# Maximum number of attempts (200) reached - Python Planet API - Order and Download a request

Tags: python, api, download, planet, order

I want to download some data from Planet using its Python API. I follow the following tutorial [planet-sdk-for-python-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/sdk-guide/#create-an-order-request](https://planet-sdk-for-python-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/sdk-guide/#create-an-order-request)

I have done the previous steps such as combined filter and have also created an order request. The json request is presented below. **I have changed item_ids for privacy reasons.**

```
{'name': 'first_attempt',
 'products': [{'item_ids': ['20230514_082356_10_100c'],
   'item_type': 'PSScene',
   'product_bundle': 'analytic_8b_sr_udm2'}],
 'tools': [{'clip': {'aoi': {'type': 'Polygon',
     'coordinates': [[[22.612246344045243, 39.51402768131731],
       [22.61671845763713, 39.51140871993713],
       [22.619159198990747, 39.50999729110945],
       [22.61978613880017, 39.50947220018895],
       [22.62023296189229, 39.508903251728995],
       [22.62151850989469, 39.50690363820488],
       [22.61615633615368, 39.50477819740085],
       [22.615389870807064, 39.50594876037168],
       [22.61504273622006, 39.50639143151726],
       [22.611913845031427, 39.50821404763483],
       [22.608655016803276, 39.51015144105115],
       [22.612246344045243, 39.51402768131731]]]}}},
  {'reproject': {'projection': 'EPSG:4326', 'kernel': 'near'}},
  {'harmonize': {'target_sensor': 'Sentinel-2'}}]}
```

In order to create the order, wait for it, and download it, I have used the following code

```
async def create_wait_and_download():
    async with Session() as sess:
        cl = sess.client('orders')
        with reporting.StateBar(state='creating') as bar:
            # create order
            order = await cl.create_order(request)
            bar.update(state='created', order_id=order['id'])

            # poll
            await cl.wait(order['id'], callback=bar.update_state)

        # download
        await cl.download_order(order['id'], "F:\ilias\Planet\draft_output", progress_bar=True)

await create_wait_and_download()
```

The problem is that the last code cell runs but after around 15 minutes I get the following error '**Maximum number of attempts (200) reached**.'

[image]

The error is shown below after some time.

[image]

The time counts up as expected until that point. If I try the same code after some time, the desired files will be downloaded and I do not get this error. How to increase the Maximum number of attempts (more than 200)? Probably, Planet needs some time to clip and prepare the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding **max_attempts=600** when I call cl.wait method that is inside the create_wait_and_download function. You could use any number you want.

```
await cl.wait(order['id'], callback=bar.update_state,  max_attempts=600)
```

max_attempts is an argument of cl.wait method.